# URL Rewrite of domain name in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, url-rewriting

I have two asp.net sites in IIS, api.mydomain.com and mobileapi.mydomain.com. and some of the requests to api should be rewritten to mobileapi. I cant get it to work. From my experiments it seems like I cant rewrite the domain name part of the url with rewrite. If I change to redirect everthing works (except that I want a rewrite and not redirect)

However, if I instead redirect to something on the same domain, lets say I swap the action url to `/testing/{R:0}` (without any domain name) then it works as expected and rewrites just fine.

My web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</modules>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Proxy mobile API" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="([^/]+)" />
        <add input="{StaticRewrites:{C:0}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^api.mydomain.se$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mobileapi.mydomain.se/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>

  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites">
      <add key="mobile" value=" " />
      <add key="scripts" value=" " />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: First question, and sorry if this is obvious, but do you have the URL Rewrite Module installed? (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear that other rewrites work :) Also note that it works fine if I change the action type to Redirect instead of Rewrite (but that is not a solution I want).

Comment: Is the rewrite done in applicationHost.config? If it is and it won't work, try routing to a server farm with rewrite.

Comment: No, the rewrite is directly in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the project type you have setup, but if you are using MVC 4 you can simply make this switch in the Global.asax.cs file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(){
   //mobile device detection and redirection
     if (Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true"){
          Response.Redirect("http://mobileapi.mydomain.se");
         }
    }
```